# Merge two list of dicts with same key

Tags: python, hash-map

I have two lists of dictionaries. Both lists always have the same ids.
I want to get the following result:

```
{9: {'av': 4, 'nv': 45}, 10: {'av': 0, 'nv': 0}, 8: {'av': 0, 'nv': 30}}
```

The following code is working but I wonder if this is the best solution?

```
l1 = [{'id': 9, 'av': 4}, {'id': 10, 'av': 0}, {'id': 8, 'av': 0}]

l2 = [{'id': 9, 'nv': 45}, {'id': 10, 'nv': 0}, {'id': 8, 'nv': 30}]


l3 = {x['id']: {'av': x['av']} for x in l1}
l4 = {x['id']: {'nv': x['nv']} for x in l2}

{key: value.update(l4[key]) for key, value in l3.items()}

>> {9: {'av': 4, 'nv': 45}, 10: {'av': 0, 'nv': 0}, 8: {'av': 0, 'nv': 30}}
```

Comment: `l1` and `l2` have their `id` in the same order, is it always the case?

Comment: The order is not always the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your approach is rather good but your implementation is hardly extensible.

For starter, you don't need `l4` as you can update `l3` directly instead:

```
l3 = {x['id']: {'av': x['av']} for x in l1}
for d in l2:
    l3[d['id']].update(nv=d['nv'])
```

Second, you can [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) the id so you don't have to know the other keys in the various dictionaries:

```
l3 = {d.pop('id'): d for d in l1}
for d in l2:
    l3[d.pop('id')].update(d)
```

But this approach has the drawback of modifying all input dictionaries. To mitigate that, we can start with an empty dictionary, update with every keys (including `id`) and pop the extra key afterwards. This is easily done using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict


result = defaultdict(dict)
for sequence in (l1, l2):
    for dictionary in sequence:
        result[dictionary['id']].update(dictionary)
for dictionary in result.values():
    dictionary.pop('id')
```

There are few overheads using this approach compared to the first version, but it is way easier to generalize so you are able to merge more than 2 lists. Speaking of which, in such case, you should define a function taking a [variable number of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/5069029) to merge:

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict


def merge(shared_key, *iterables)
    result = defaultdict(dict)
    for dictionary in itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterables):
        result[dictionary[shared_key]].update(dictionary)
    for dictionary in result.values():
        dictionary.pop(shared_key)
    return result
```

Usage be like

```
merge('id', l1, l2)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to merge lists of dicts, you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

`pandas` might be a 800-pound gorilla but it's included in many distros, is well tested and documented.

You just need to initialize the [dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#dataframe), set their index and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) them:

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = [{'id': 9, 'av': 4}, {'id': 10, 'av': 0}, {'id': 8, 'av': 0}]
l2 = [{'id': 9, 'nv': 45}, {'id': 10, 'nv': 0}, {'id': 8, 'nv': 30}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1).set_index('id')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(l2).set_index('id')
df = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df.T.to_dict()
# {9: {'av': 4, 'nv': 45}, 10: {'av': 0, 'nv': 0}, 8: {'av': 0, 'nv': 30}}
```

Here's the corresponding console output:

```
>>> l1 = [{'id': 9, 'av': 4}, {'id': 10, 'av': 0}, {'id': 8, 'av': 0}]
>>> l2 = [{'id': 9, 'nv': 45}, {'id': 10, 'nv': 0}, {'id': 8, 'nv': 30}]
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1).set_index('id')
>>> df1
    av
id    
9    4
10   0
8    0
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(l2).set_index('id')
>>> df2
    nv
id    
9   45
10   0
8   30
>>> df = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
>>> df
    av  nv
id        
9    4  45
10   0   0
8    0  30
>>> df.T.to_dict()
{9: {'av': 4, 'nv': 45}, 10: {'av': 0, 'nv': 0}, 8: {'av': 0, 'nv': 30}}
```

Comment: Heavy handed, but nice solution.